# Magento Triggering Queries

Tags: mysql, magento

As am Mysql Dba new in Magento FrameWork am unable to find from where the Magento queries are triggering can any tell me the location from where these queries are running

Comment: Try somethink else, why magento. I etered my email to get demo, but he send me spam

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified which modules data files. Or which query you want to check. Mangento use MVC structure. You will find all data related operations in model. It will be located in app/code/codepool/namespace/module/model

Here code pool will be local or community and third is core but if you want modified file from core copy in local and make changes.

Namespace will be company name and module will be module name.

Hope this will help.

Comment: for ex i need queries which are running in dashboard module

Comment: so you need to check in model files of dashboard module. You can use any debug tool to find appropriate class. or give us example which data query you want so we can also help. Thanks